# ElasticSearch: greater between two aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm new to ElasticSearch and I am trying to get the greater value between two aggregations, is it possible? I need the greater between avg_field1 and avg_field2.

I was thinking in try to use `script: max`, but I didn't find any example of this usage.. I don't even know if it's possible.

My aggregations are like this now:

```
{
 "aggs" : {
   "group_by_frame" : {
       "histogram" : {
           "field" : "index_histogram",
           "interval" : 100
       },
       "aggs" : {
           "avg_field1" : { "avg" : { "field" : "field1" } },
           "avg_field2" : { "avg" : { "field" : "field2" } }
       }

   }
 }
```

Comment: Why can't you compute the max value on the client side? Doesn't sound that difficult.

Comment: It isn't difficult, but I wonder if i can do that at server side, without any post-processing

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer here: [Elastic Search SUM of aggregated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405491/elastic-search-sum-of-aggregated-values)

Basically you cannot aggregate over different aggregations.