# Elastic Search SUM of aggregated values

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using elastic search to get some statics.

1. I need to get average values for each group.
2. Sum all this values

So far, step no. 1 was pretty straight forward. However I really don't know how to sum all values at the end. Is this possible? If yes, how?.

Thanks for suggestions.
Here is my aggs query >

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "filtered":{  
         "query":{  
            "query_string":{  
               "analyze_wildcard":true,
               "query":"*"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs":{  
      "2":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"person",
            "size":5000,
            "order":{  
               "1":"desc"
            }
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "1":{  
               "avg":{  
                  "field":"company"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregating over aggregation results are not yet supported in elasticsearch. Apparently there is a concept called [reducers](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8110) that are being developed for 2.0.  I would suggest having a look at [scripted metric aggregations](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html). Basically, you can create your own aggregation by controlling the collection and computation aspects yourself using scripts.

Alternatively, if possible you can precompute and store the average when indexing and then use the sum aggregation when querying.

Have a look at the following question for an example of this aggregation: [Elasticsearch: Possible to process aggregation results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992154/elasticsearch-possible-to-process-aggregation-results)